# IE autologin Script

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, autologin

I'm trying to have a script which open an URL and submit the login and password, the below script is what I have found so far but I'm getting the below error.

**Script :**

```
       Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       IE.navigate "URL"
       IE.Visible = True

       While IE.Busy

       WScript.Sleep 50

       Wend

       Set ipf = IE.document.all.username

       ipf.Value = "username" 

       Set ipf = IE.document.all.password

       ipf.Value = "password" 
       Set ipf = IE.document.all.Submit
       ipf.Click 
       IE.Quit`
```

**All submit Error :**

[image: Error]

Comment: Please share the URL or the entire webpage HTML content. Seems there is no such node named `username` on the page, which is being accessed in line 13.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I cannot share the real URL due to some privacy reasons, if I want to have this script successful with Facebook,com for example, what should be amended within this script ?

Comment: All sites are different, so I'm not sure that solution for Facebook can be adapted for other. That's why I'm asking you to share at least the entire webpage HTML content.

Comment: This is helpful for me, and I was able to adjust it for my website. I want to use the script for a website that regularly logs me out, and I want to automate the log-in process.

How would I adapt the code to keep attempting a login every, say, half-hour?